# Why is a LibraryLink function, which returns a list, not parallelizing with ParallelTable?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, librarylink

**First example**: librarylink function return a list of two element

```
libsource = "#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

  DLLEXPORT int returnlist(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, \
MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
  mreal x;
  x = MArgument_getReal(Args[0]);

  MTensor out_MT;
  const mint out_dim[]={2};
  mint out_rank=1;
  int err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, out_rank, out_dim, \
&out_MT);
  mreal *out_cpointer=libData->MTensor_getRealData(out_MT);

  out_cpointer[0]=x;
  out_cpointer[1]=x;

  MArgument_setMTensor(Res,out_MT);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }";
```

load it with

```
Clear[lib]
lib = CreateLibrary[libsource, "returnlist", "Debug" -> True, 
   "CompileOptions" -> "-x c"];
returnlist = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "returnlist", {Real}, {Real, 1}];
```

and now `returnlist[2]` gives `{2.,2.}`

Timing of sequential `Table`

```
Table[returnlist[i], {i, 1, 600000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.642416, Null}*)

ParallelTable[returnlist[i], {i, 1, 600000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{22.8262, Null}*)
```

If we look at the CPU load when evaluating `ParallelTable`, it shows that it only use one kernel

[image]

**Second example**, slight modification to the previous function to let it return only one number.

```
libsource = "#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

  EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int returnnum(WolframLibraryData libData, mint \
Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
  mreal x;
  x = MArgument_getReal(Args[0]);

  MTensor out_MT;
  const mint out_dim[]={2};
  mint out_rank=1;
  //-----------if tensor is real---------
  int err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Real, out_rank, out_dim, \
&out_MT);
  mreal *out_cpointer=libData->MTensor_getRealData(out_MT);

  out_cpointer[0]=x;
  out_cpointer[1]=x;

  MArgument_setReal(Res,out_cpointer[0]);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }";
```

load it with

```
LibraryFunctionUnload[returnnum]
Clear[lib];
lib = CreateLibrary[libsource, "returnnum", "Debug" -> True, 
   "CompileOptions" -> "-x c"];
returnnum = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "returnnum", {Real}, Real];
```

Now `returnnum[2]` gives `2.`.

Timing of `Table`

```
Table[returnnum[i], {i, 1, 6000000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{6.23547,Null}*)

ParallelTable[returnnum[i], {i, 1, 6000000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{7.46414,Null}*)
```

If we look at the CPU load when evaluating `ParallelTable`, it shows that it is parallelized now

[image]

**Why is this? How to make librarylink function that return list be parallelized?**

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but after a quick skim through the post it seems that the library function was only loaded on the main kernel.  You must also load it explicitly (`LibraryFunctionLoad`) on each subkernel.  Use `ParalleEvaluate` for this.  I do use LibraryLink stuff with parallelization, but it usually is put in a Mathematica package (`.m` file) which has code for loading the library functions and which is read in using `ParallelNeeds` (in addition to standard `Needs`).

Comment: @Szabolcs You mean like this `ParallelEvaluate[  returnlist =    LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "returnlist", {Real}, {Real, 1}]];` ? But I got errors like "LibraryFunction::noopen: Cannot open lib."

Comment: @Szabolcs Full path didn't work. What do you mean by using `$LibraryPath`?

Comment: After looking more carefully: you must `DistributeDefinitions[lib]` before doing this.  `ParallelEvaluate` does not automatically do it (like `ParallelTable` does). I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Szabolcs Let me try it. But I am a question maybe not relevant. I often got errors like "CopyFile::filex: "Cannot overwrite existing file "C:......\\ Windows-x86-64\\ returnlist.dll"", and I tried to `LibraryUnload[lib]` and it will show "LibraryFunction::unloadlib: "The library \!\(\"C:\\.....\\Windows-x86-64\\\\returnlist.dll\"\) cannot be unloaded. " What is wrong, How to avoid this? Currently, I have to restart Kernel to get the library create and load again correctly

Comment: @Szabolcs and `DistributeDefinitions[lib]` first also didn't work

Comment: That's a different question.  On Windows the library must be unloaded `LibraryUnload` before it can be recompiled.  Not sure if this is necessary on other platforms as well.  Please see my message in chat.